# new Set constructor not working on safari

Tags: javascript

Below concat is not working on safari nor IE, seems like new Set cant be used, what would be the alternative to concat after removing part of a string

```
var allSoundsMod = [].concat(_toConsumableArray(new Set(allSounds.map(function (sound) {
    return sound.split('_')[0];
}))));
```

So I fixed with

```
var allSoundsMod = [].concat(_toConsumableArray(allSounds.map(function (sound) {
    return sound.split('_')[0];
})));
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Set is not a function... just edited the op seems taht is working but i am  not 100% if its correct

Comment: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ — It should work. Perhaps you are using old versions of those browsers which don't support it.

Comment: It doesnt work on IOS, both chrome and safari are giving errors. my fix worked fine